# Detaching a string into two using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am getting the date from data base in this format, '01/02/2013 17:00'. I have to detach the date and time and put it in separate columns in the nstableview (date in date column and time in time column). How should i do this?

Comment: What you have tried and where you are facing problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can:

```
NSArray *dateAndTime = [@"01/02/2013 17:00" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

This if you are certain about that format. Otherwise you should be careful and rely on something like `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateTime = @"01/02/2013 17:00";

NSArray *strings = [dateTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

The array strings will now look like...

```
[
    @"01/02/2013",
    @"17:00"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change to time format, or want more control over the times etc. I recommend a NSDateFormatter..

```
    NSString *dateString = @"'01/02/2013 17:00";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm"];

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
    NSString *newDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *newTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```